# UnsatisfiedLinkError using jblas in Android for Matrix exponential

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror, jblas

I need to use matrix exponential function for my **Android** application. I have used the library **jblas** (jblas.org). But it returns the following error and the application crashes!

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void         
org.jblas.NativeBlas.dgemm(char, char, int, int, int, double, double[], 
int, int, double[], int, int, double, double[], int, int) (tried 
Java_org_jblas_NativeBlas_dgemm and 
Java_org_jblas_NativeBlas_dgemm__CCIIID_3DII_3DIID_3DII)
        at org.jblas.NativeBlas.dgemm(Native Method)
        at org.jblas.SimpleBlas.gemm(SimpleBlas.java:247)
        at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.mmuli(DoubleMatrix.java:1781)
        at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.mmul(DoubleMatrix.java:3138)
        at org.jblas.MatrixFunctions.expm(MatrixFunctions.java:428)
```

Comment: you need have the corresponding `.so` in place for the required ABI, e.g. `arm64-v8a` for most of devices and `x86` or `x86_64` for emulators. So, do check if you have them inside your apk.

Comment: @shizhen If possible may I know the respective .so I need and how to include it in my apk?

Comment: **jblas** was not originally for Android, in order to make it work on Android, maybe you need to add the jar but also need to compile its C source code for the required ABIs.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps to get an Android version of **jblas**:

1. Checkout the source code of **jblas** from: https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas
2. Recompile the c source code: https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas/tree/master/src/main/c using Android CMake tool chains. You will get the required shared libs, e.g. `arm64-v8a`, `x86` or `x86_64`.

Comment: It generates the following warnings if I run the code :                                        
  1) warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void **' to parameter of type 'JNIEnv **' (aka 'const struct JNINativeInterface ***') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    (*JVMcache)->AttachCurrentThread(JVMcache, (void **)&envPtr, NULL); // attach this thread to the globally cache JVM

Comment: And also, warning: implicitly declaring library function 'cimag' with type 'double (_Complex double)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  return createObject(env, CORE_PACKAGE "ComplexDouble", "(DD)V", creal(dc), cimag(dc)); note: include the header <complex.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'cimag' Even if the header <complex.h> is already included!!